# How to get specific column names while exporting to csv?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm exporting some data from mysql to csv using php.
I'm doing this to get the colum names.

```
$columns = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='schema' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='table'"
);
$columns->execute();
$results_columns = $columns->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
```

I already know which columns I need. To get the data I did this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

But now I need some specific names not all of them. How do I do this?

Comment: If you know the column names you want, why do you need to retrieve them from the database?

Comment: Because I need the name of each column inside the file

Comment: How would you determine which columns you want?

Comment: No @miken32 point was that if you have to code the columns name you want from this query, why bother with the query.

Comment: Do the column names you want match a pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the point of what you're doing, but the obvious answer seems to be this:

```
$columns = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='schema' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')"
);
$columns->execute();
$results_columns = $columns->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
```